# How to send a POST request from a vanila JS application?

Tags: vue.js, fetch

I've created a single page `index.html` that contains a simple form with an input, when I click on the form button I want to send a `POST` request to my server, however the browser keep saying:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.....' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The request code is basicaly:

```
fetch('https://api.....', { method: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify({}) })
```

I didn't build a server using node, it's just a `index.html` with `vuejs 2` in it, can I send this post request without a server?

Comment: You can try cors extension for a browser, but actually, it's better to come up with a proper setup. A lot of web apps aren't supposed to be used without web server, this can prevent some things from working like a router. And cors is naturally handled by devserver proxy in vue cli setup or else. If it's not your api and you can't end up with correct cors in production, you'll need node proxy any way. One of reasons why cors is used is to prevent random websites from using your api without restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like that.

However, it seems that the API you're contacting does not allow the header `content-type` in its `CORS` policy. This header was included because you're doing a `POST` request containing some data.

You could try setting `mode` to `no-cors` but you should note that this does not guarantee that it works.

```
fetch('https://api.....', { method: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify({}), "mode": "no-cors" })
```

Comment: By using `mode: no-cors` I cannot send a `application/json` as `content-type`, here's the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Comment: @RafaAcioly Is this really the case? It says "the headers from being anything other than simple headers". content-type can be considered simple header

Comment: yes, simple header consist in one of these `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data", or "text/plain"`